# NHibernate: Reading mysql Blob field - value returned as "System.Byte[]"

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a class with a property:

```
virtual public string Data { get; set; }
```

example.hbm.xml binds that to:

```
<property name="Data" type="string" column="data" ></property>
```

The table in MySql is created with:

```
CREATE TABLE `xxx` (
 `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `data` blob,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=binary;
```

I can successfully write to the db and I can see the text in the column written properly.

When I try to read records from this table the value of the 'Data' property is 'System.Byte[]'. Again this is the value of this property. It's type is 'System.String'.

What to do? Thanks in advance for any clues.

I tried charset=UTF8 too.

I also tried type="StringClob" in the mapping file.

Thanks 
Tymek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to read and write this as a byte[].  So you're property definition would look like this instead:

```
public virtual byte[] Data { get; set; }
```

In addition to this change you will need to change the type in your mapping.  I'm not sure what the type.  I think it may be blob.

You can easily convert this data to a string if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no MySQL expert, but you probably want the column type to be `text` instead of `blob`.

With that, `type="StringClob"` should work

Comment: You are totally right, but as the db schema is already in place I'll mark "read it as byte[]" as the best answer.

Comment: @Tymek: that's fine. Keep in mind you'll have to use an Encoding if you want to read it as text.